# Ruby on Rails: Polymorphic Association, associating tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphic-associations

I'm working on polymorphic association, but how do I correctly call certain values in my database.

If I have these tables

**Book table**

```
 id | title            
  1 | give me something
  2 | more title names please
```

**Author table**

```
 id | name
  1 | Author Goods
```

**Review table**

```
 id | author_id | reviewable_id | reviewable_type | review
 1  |    1    |       1       |       Book        | Don't read this book
 2  |    2    |       2       |       Book        | This book is awesome
 3  |    2    |       1       |      Author       | Love this author
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@reviews = Review.where(user_id: current_user)
```

My html loops like this:

```
<% @reviews.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.author %> <!-- this will give me author information -->
<% end %>
```

With `r.author`, I can get information from author, but what if I'm trying to access information of author and book with reviewable_type? I can't do `r.reviewable_type` because, theres no id association. If I don't have the column `book_id` like `author_id` in my **Review** table, how do I get **Book** information if my only association through reviewable type is the name of the tables not the id?

I hope my explanation of my issue makes sense.

Comment: Why do you not have the id? If it is associated then I dont see why there isnt reviewable_id.

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 my reviewable_id is there. but its only connected to the associated `reviewable_type` names, but I'm not sure what the Ruby syntax to get the associated id with the `reviewable_type` and `reviewable_id`

Answer (score 0):

firstly u dont need author_id in Review if it is polymorphic.

your review.rb should look like

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and your book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

similar should be for your author.rb also

now u dont need to query Review table directly , if u want all current_user reviews
simply do

```
@reviews = current_user.reviews
```

it will fetch all records from `reviews table` which have reviewable_id == current_user.id and reviewable_type == "User"

u can similarly query for Books reviews also.

Comment: I want to reference the author name with each review. This way I can do 1 loop and that loop, I'll be able to get the name of the author, the review, and anything else I can get.

Comment: u can loop through "@reviews" like @reviews.each { |r| r.reviewable.name } it will give u author name if reviewable_type is "Author"